How to create a custom draggable table with depth but only having the deepest depth draggable
Here is what I achieved so far wich is pretty much the look and feel that I want except that it does not work as intended. (In my example, I want the end user to only be able to switch My node 1 and My node 2 within My term 2

Here is my custom code :
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="faq-draggable-table">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#header' => [
    'data' => $this->t('Title'),
    'operations' => $this->t('Operation'),
    'weight' => $this->t('Weight'),
  ],
  '#attributes' => [
    'id' => 'item-order-table',
  ],
  '#tabledrag' => [
    [
      'action' => 'match',
      'relationship' => 'parent',
      'group' => 'item-parent',
      'source' => 'item-id',
      'hidden' => FALSE,
      'limit' => 2,
    ],
    [
      'action' => 'order',
      'relationship' => 'sibling',
      'group' => 'draggable-weight',
    ],
  ],
];
$itemsOrdered = $this->getAllElementStructured();
foreach ($itemsOrdered as $themeWeight => $theme) {
  $this->buildSubTable($form, 'theme', $theme, $themeWeight);
  foreach ($theme['subThemes'] as $subThemeWeight => $subTheme) {
    $this->buildSubTable($form, 'sub_theme', $subTheme, $subThemeWeight, 1, 'theme:' . $theme['id']);
    foreach ($subTheme['faqItems'] as $faqItemWeight => $faqItem) {
      $this->buildSubTable($form, 'faq_item', $faqItem, $faqItemWeight, 2, 'sub_theme:' . $subTheme['id']);
    }
  }
}

private function buildSubTable(
  &$form,
  string $type,
  array $item,
  int $weight = 0,
  int $depth = 0,
  ?string $parentId = NULL): void {
  ['label' => $label, 'id' => $id, 'url' => $url] = $item;
  $indentation = [];
  if ($depth > 0) {
    $indentation = [
      '#theme' => 'indentation',
      '#size' => $depth,
    ];
  }
  $weightClass = [];
  $attributes = [];
  if ($type === 'faq_item') {
    $attributes = [
      'class' => ['draggable'],
    ];
    $weightClass = ['draggable-weight'];
  }
  $form['table'][$type . ':' . $id] = [
    'data' => [
      '#markup' => $label,
      '#prefix' => !empty($indentation) ? $this->renderer->render($indentation) : '',
      'id' => [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $type . ':' . $id,
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['item-id'],
        ],
      ],
      'parent' => [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#default_value' => $parentId,
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['item-parent'],
        ],
      ],
    ],
    'operations' => [
      '#type' => 'operations',
      '#links' => [
        'edit' => [
          'title' => $this->t('Edit'),
          'weight' => 10,
          'url' => $url,
        ],
      ],
    ],
    'weight' => [
      '#type' => 'weight',
      '#title' => $this->t('Weight'),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
      '#default_value' => $weight,
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => $weightClass,
      ],
    ],
    '#attributes' => $attributes,
  ];
}

The problem is that when I drag and drop the items depth changes. I want it to be fixed and only be able to drag and drop node item within their term and only within their term.
I don't know if that's possible. I read the documentation and tried multiple things without any success and therefore I'm asking for help :-)
